# Update Multiple Models in yii

Tags: php, join, yii, model, multi-model-forms

I have 3 tabs on my view file

**First tab:**  student

**Second tab:** education

**Third tab:** employment

### My Table Structure:

**student table:**

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
|    id(PK)   |  lead_id   |  st_name     |   st_email |  st_phone   |
+-------------+------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

**Lead Details:**

```
+-------------+-------------+
|    id(PK)   | lead_ref_id |  
+-------------+-------------+
```

**Education**

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|    id(PK)   |  lead_id   |education_type|education_year|
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**Employment:**

```
+-------------+------------+---------------+---------------------+
|    id(PK)   |  lead_id   |Employment_type|Employment_experience|
+-------------+------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

When I go to the update action, I have to show data according to the lead_id

**My student view file code:**

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'lead-student-detail-form',
// Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
// controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.

// See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    )); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>



<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'st_name'); ?>
    <?php echo   $form->textField($model,'st_name',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'st_name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'st_email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'st_email',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'st_email'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'st_phone'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'st_phone'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'st_phone'); ?>
</div>



    </div><!-- form -->
```

**My education view code**

```
 <div class="form">

 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'lead-target-education-form',
// Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
// controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
// There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
// See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
  )); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary(array($target)); ?>


</div>

    <?php echo $form->labelEx($target,'education_type'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($target,'education_type'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($target,'education_type'); ?>

  </div>    


</div>

    <?php echo $form->labelEx($target,'academic_year'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($target,'academic_year[]'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($target,'academic_year'); ?>

  </div>
```

How should i write the action update code so data shows according to the `lead_id`, not by the primary key `id` and get update according to the `lead_id`.

***Update From Comment***

There is a one to many relationship between lead and education tables.

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|    id(PK)   |  lead_id   |education_type|education_year|
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+ 
|     1       |    1       |    10        |    2003      |
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|     2       |    1       |    12        |    2005      |
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: each tab have different model. right?

Comment: yes models are differnt for each tab

Comment: Did you use `realations()` in your models. It make it too easier for joining, and in brief, your controller, you should insert and update models step by step in the main insertion controller and then if everything ok, save the main controller data and redirect it.[creating-and-updating-model-and-its-related-models...](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/384/creating-and-updating-model-and-its-related-models-in-one-form-inc-image), [how-to-use-multiple-instances-...](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/362/how-to-use-multiple-instances-of-the-same-model-in-the-same-form)

Comment: thanks for the solution I have Multiple entries regarding the lead_id how can I fetch all the values regarding the lead_id as findByPk() fetchs only one row and findAll() functions fetchecs the values but it doesn't show the result its throwing the error <b>Trying to get property of non-object</b>

Comment: Please provide your current controller code and also please include a dump of the data that is posted to the controller when updating.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you just need to do a find. So what you will end up with is

```
$lead_id = 1;

$student = Student::model()->find(array('condition'=>'lead_id = :lead_id','params'=>array(':lead_id'=>$lead_id)));
$student->name = 'newvalue';
$student->save();

$education = Education::model()->find(array('condition'=>'lead_id = :lead_id','params'=>array(':lead_id'=>$lead_id)));
$education->education_year = 'newvalue';
$education->save();

$employment = Employment::model()->find(array('condition'=>'lead_id = :lead_id','params'=>array(':lead_id'=>$lead_id)));
$employment->employment_type = 'newvalue';
$employment->save();
```

Here we have accessed three models using find. We feed in the `lead_id` via the parameter `:lead_id`, this is the bound to the lead_id variable `':lead_id'=>$lead_id`

Then I can change the fields as shown, using the `$model->save();` function to save the new information.

If this is not the info you are after then please comment and I will update with your suggestions.

Comment: I have multiple Entries Regarding the education of a student like  <table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>lead_id</td>
    <td>Education Type</td>
    <td>Education Year</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>10 th</td>
    <td>2003</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>12 th</td>
    <td>2005</td>
    </tr>
    </table>  with lead_id is common and i have tried the find and  it only fetch one row but not the another row Please Help.

Comment: Change `Education::model()->find` to `Education::model()->findAll`, then loop through `$educatiom`

Comment: Thanks for the solution its works in the view part but it is showing error in update page Fatal error: Call to a member function getErrors() on a non-object

Comment: @nitin No worries, glad you got it sorted.